# combining multiple rows into 1

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, oracle-sqldeveloper, crosstab

I have a table with courses from another school that tie to corresponding courses at our school. It is a one to many relation ship
I'm trying to line it up all on one line based on the transferring school's course
for example

```
schoolcode | subj | crsenum  |  oursubj  |  ourcrsenum
------------------------------------------------------
1234       | Art  | 100      |  VisArt   |     200
1234       | Art  | 100      |  VisArt   |     201
```

outcome I'm trying to get is

```
schoolcode | subj | crsnum  | oursubj1   | ourcrsnum1  |  oursubj2 | ourcrsnum2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1234       | Art  | 100     | VisArt     |    200      |  VisArt   |  201
```

what I've tried still gives me two lines per transfer school course 
in the table there is also a sequence number corresponding to each course added that is attached to the one incoming course
any help would be greatly appreciated!
thanks

I apologize...
I'm working in oracle/sqldeveloper
this is information from one table where I'm just trying to select it and flatten it out to one row where the key is the schoolcode|subj|crsenum 
and then add to that row, all courses that we have associated with that one course. if there are more than 2, I would like to add it to the same row
so for example if for school 1234 subj Art crsenum 100 there is also a course Drawing 200 at our school - I would like it to give me

```
1234     |  Art  | 100 | VisArt  | 200   | VisArt  | 201 | Drawing | 200
```

I hope that makes sense
this is my first question ever

Comment: What rdbms are you working with? What happens if you have more than 2 lines?

Comment: what query are you using? when you say you get two lines, are the `ourcrsnum1` and `ourcrsnum2` the same, but with the values swapped?

Comment: ah, I think I see what you are trying to do, do you want all the matching courses compiled into a single row? For example, all courses with a `crsenum` of 100 to have an arbitrary number of `oursubj` and `ourcrsenum` columns, depending on the number of rows? (I don't know if my wording is very clear)

Comment: This is a pivot on oursubj and ourcrsenum.  Pivot can be handled lots of ways.  but pivot only works if the number of columns to create is static.  if not meaning the number of rows to combine could be 'N' then you need Dynamic SQL to handle the unknown number of columns.    I would note that transforming the data this way is often better done in the Presentation Layer.  DB's store, retrieve, and aggregate data; they really are not meant to make the data look pretty.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Comment: I edited the original question  - hopefully I make more sense?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @tbl VARCHAR(100)

SET @tbl = 'courses' -- put your table name here

SET @sql = 'SELECT schoolcode, subj, crsenum, ' 

SELECT @sql = @sql + ''''+ oursubj + '''' + ' AS oursubj' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ourcrsenum) AS VARCHAR) + ', ' + CAST(ourcrsenum AS VARCHAR) + ' AS crsenum' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ourcrsenum) AS VARCHAR) + ', '
  FROM courses

SET @sql = LEFT(@sql, LEN(@sql) - 1)

SET @sql = @sql + ' FROM ' + @tbl + ' GROUP BY schoolcode, subj, crsenum'

EXEC(@sql)
```

Result

```
schoolcode | subj | crsenum | oursubj1 | crsenum1 | oursubj2 | crsenum2
1234       | Art  | 100     | VisArt   | 200      | VisArt   | 201
```